# I want to list out the lines which are having older date than the current date through shell script

Tags: file, date, filter, format, line

Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 30, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 24, 2023
Jan 11, 2018
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 27, 2017
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 03, 2023
Oct 15, 2023
Nov 28, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Oct 15, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 28, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Nov 13, 2023
Nov 20, 2023
Oct 25, 2023
Nov 26, 2023
Nov 20, 2023

Lets say today date in format date '+%b %d, %Y' is Sep 01, 2023

I want all the lines listed from above file which are having date in same format and less than "Sep 01, 2023"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.